# Java foreach recursive return (number of children in a tree)

Tags: java, recursion, foreach, tree

I'm having a problem with a simple recursive function that should return the number of children in a tree, it only goes in the first child of every children ignoring the foreach probably because the function already returned something.
I don't know what to do.

```
public static int numberOfChildren(Node<Integer> a) {
    if(!a.isLeaf()) {
        for(Node<Integer> f : a.getChildren()) {
            return 1 + numberOfChildren(f);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int nbr = 1;
for (Node<Integer> f: a.getChildren()) {
nbr += numberOfChildren(f);
}
return nbr;
```

Comment: Thank you, so I can't return a recursive call of a function in a foreach, right ?

Comment: You can do that, but that stops the execution of the loop. Sometimes you may want that. In this particular case you need to return the sum of the recursive call for each child-node. Thus, aggregate the results and return the sum.